# Sitecore PowerShell Select item at Show-ListView has no delete action

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to find media items that has no references,  but user should have an option to delete them manually .
by some reason, if I add an item to custom noRefeItems, Show-ListView component does not show delete action. how to fix it?

```
$noRefeItems = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $itemsToProcess = Get-ChildItem -Path  $root.ProviderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq 'Image' }
    if ($itemsToProcess -ne $null) {
        $itemsToProcess | ForEach-Object {
            $referrers = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $_ | measure
            if ($referrers.Count -gt 0) {
               
            } else {
                $noRefeItems.Add($_)
               
            }
        }
    }
    
    $noRefeItems | Show-ListView -Property DisplayName, ProviderPath, Size, Created
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete buttons do not exist in reports by default. If you wish to add your own custom report actions then you can following the documentation described [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/reports/authoring-reports#report-actions). You can make the action do whatever you want, such as delete the item and send an email.

The training module included with SPE provides an example report action.

[image: Content Tree]

The Advanced Report example demonstrates the "Say Hello" button.

[image: Action]